# Android :android.jar is neither a directory nor file (type =1)

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-build

I installed android studio using the bundle. I was trying to run my first app, but it is showing following message during the gradle build :

```
    W/asset ( 5224): Asset path C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar is neither a directory nor file (type=1).

    ERROR: Asset package include 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar' not found.
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    Information:BUILD FAILED
```

android.jar file is present at the above path.
Can anyone please help me what must be wrong in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly this might be some sort of permission issue. I would suggest move your sdk to some drive other than c drive and try again.
I am suggesting this as you said android.jar is present and still it is saying not found.